# Artificial intelligence used to come up with recipe, based on picture, and optionally taste, input

Tags: artificial-intelligence, cooking

Is there any softare that users artificial intelligence (AI) to come up with a given recipe for a dish based on information on how the food looks and tastes.

The software, ideally available in smartphones, should, ideally, do the following:

Let you:

- Take a picture of food.
- Optionally, add information on how it tastes.

The AI, comes up with, possible recipes (preparation and cooking instructions), for the given dish.

Where can I find such software?

Thank you for your involvement, contribution, and, implementation

Thanks